# About the hardware recommendation for Unreal Engine 5

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, game-development

I want to delve into game development next month and I know I need a very good PC, but I'm a student and can have very little money to spare.

I'm eyeing an [Acer Swift 3 Ryzen](https://www.acer.com/us-en/laptops/swift/swift-3-amd/pdp/NX.AB1AA.00B) with the following specs:
Ryzen 7 5700U
16GB RAM DDR4
512GB SSD
Shared Graphics Memory AMD Radeon RX Vega 8 Graphics.
I want to know if it's **good enough** for Unreal 5, or perhaps I should just stick to 3d modelling and Graphics design for now. I'd have relied on the specs I see online, but content on this topic is vague and is claimed by several sources to be unreliable. I need advice from someone who has actually tried something similar or has been in a similar situation. Or in fact, anyone who has something important to say.

Good advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The storage and RAM on that laptop is a little low for UE5. I would reccomend at least 32GB RAM and 1TB storage (the storage can be a NAS too though)

Comment: "good enough for Unreal 5" is way to vague to work with. If you're making games with Unreal Engine then you need to provide more information about the kind of graphics the game needs to render. Using all of the amazing new tech in Unreal 5 is not mandatory and the engine can still be used to render *much* simpler graphics that run fast.